# OnClick listener not working on views in a CustomLayout extending ViewGroup

Tags: android, android-layout, youtube, touch-event, viewgroup

I have tried to implement the youtube like draggable panel using the Customlayout which extends ViewGroup. I have made use of the onTouchEvents to create and scaling on dragging effect.

1. Now, the problem is that the when dragged down, the selected item resides near the  bottom of the screen as it happens in YouTube. When clicked on that item in that position, it should get back to the full screen mode. But to do so, I implemented the onClicklistener for the view but it simply doesn't respond.
2. Also, when at the bottom,  how do I restrict it's motion in the vertical direction and allow it to move in the horizontal direction as it happens in YouTube.

Here is the CustomLayout class called DraggablePanel.

```
    package visio.com.eventpage;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.support.v4.view.MotionEventCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.ViewDragHelper;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static android.view.MotionEvent.INVALID_POINTER_ID;

/**
 * Created by Rambo on 1/9/2018.
 */

public class DraggablePanel extends ViewGroup  {


    public final ViewDragHelper mDragHelper;

    public View mHeaderView;
    private View mDescView;

    private float mInitialMotionX;
    private float mInitialMotionY;

    private int mDragRange;
    private int mTop;
    private float mDragOffset;
    private Context context;
    public int toponViewReleased;

    public int screenWidth, screenHeight;

    private String TAG = "DraggablePanel";
    public void manualInvalidate(){
        invalidate();
    }

    public DraggablePanel(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public DraggablePanel(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
        mHeaderView = findViewById(R.id.viewHeader);
        mDescView = findViewById(R.id.viewDesc);

        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        ((Activity)context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        screenHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
        screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

    }

    public DraggablePanel(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        mDragHelper = ViewDragHelper.create(this, 1f, new DragHelperCallback());

    }


    private class DragHelperCallback extends ViewDragHelper.Callback {

        @Override
        public boolean tryCaptureView(View child, int pointerId) {
            return child == mHeaderView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewPositionChanged(View changedView, int left, int top, int dx, int dy) {
            mTop = top;


                float paddingOffset = (float)top/10;

                mDragOffset = (float) top / mDragRange;
                mHeaderView.setPivotX(mHeaderView.getWidth());
                mHeaderView.setPivotY(mHeaderView.getHeight());
                mHeaderView.setScaleX(1 - mDragOffset / 2);
                mHeaderView.setScaleY(1 - mDragOffset / 2);
                mHeaderView.setPadding(0,0,(int) paddingOffset, (int) paddingOffset);
                mDescView.setAlpha(1 - mDragOffset);

                if( top == 0){

                }

            requestLayout();

            Log.d("onViewPositionChanged","Called");
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewReleased(View releasedChild, float xvel, float yvel) {

            int top = releasedChild.getTop()>screenHeight/3?screenHeight-150 - mHeaderView.getHeight():0;
            Log.d("Heights","H1"+getHeight() + "child height" + releasedChild.getMeasuredHeight()+"top" +top);

            mDragHelper.smoothSlideViewTo(releasedChild, releasedChild.getLeft(),top);

            if( top!=0 ){
                mDescView.setAlpha(0);
            }
            ViewCompat.postInvalidateOnAnimation(releasedChild);
            toponViewReleased = top;

            invalidate();
        }

        @Override
        public int getViewVerticalDragRange(View child) {
            return mDragRange;
        }


        @Override
        public int clampViewPositionVertical(View child, int top, int dy) {

            float descViewAlpha = mDescView.getAlpha();

            final int topBound = getPaddingTop();
            final int bottomBound = getHeight() - mHeaderView.getHeight() - 20;

            int newTop = Math.min(Math.max(top, topBound), bottomBound);
            if( descViewAlpha == 0 ){
                    newTop = 0;
            }
            Log.d(TAG,"clampVertical" + newTop);
            return newTop;
        }

        @Override
        public int clampViewPositionHorizontal(View child, int left, int dx) {
            final int rightBound = mHeaderView.getPaddingRight();
            final int leftBound = screenWidth - mHeaderView.getWidth() - 20;

            int newTop = Math.min(Math.max(left, rightBound), leftBound);
            if(mDescView.getAlpha() != 0){
                newTop = 0;
            }

            Log.d(TAG,"clampHorizontal" + newTop);
            return newTop;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void computeScroll() {
        if (mDragHelper.continueSettling(true)) {
            ViewCompat.postInvalidateOnAnimation(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        final int action = ev.getActionMasked();

        if (( action != MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)) {
            mDragHelper.cancel();
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
        }

        final float x = ev.getX();
        final float y = ev.getY();
        boolean interceptTap = false;

        switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                mInitialMotionX = x;
                mInitialMotionY = y;
                interceptTap = mDragHelper.isViewUnder(mHeaderView, (int) x, (int) y);
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                final float adx = Math.abs(x - mInitialMotionX);
                final float ady = Math.abs(y - mInitialMotionY);
                final int slop = mDragHelper.getTouchSlop();
                if (ady > slop && adx > ady) {
                    mDragHelper.cancel();
                    return false;
                }
            }

        }

        return mDragHelper.shouldInterceptTouchEvent(ev) || interceptTap;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        mDragHelper.processTouchEvent(ev);

        final int action = ev.getAction();
        final float x = ev.getX();
        final float y = ev.getY();

        boolean isHeaderViewUnder = mDragHelper.isViewUnder(mHeaderView, (int) x, (int) y);
        switch (action & ev.getActionMasked()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                mInitialMotionX = x;
                mInitialMotionY = y;
                break;
            }

        }

        return isHeaderViewUnder && isViewHit(mHeaderView, (int) x, (int) y) || isViewHit(mDescView, (int) x, (int) y);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean performClick() {
        super.performClick();
        if(toponViewReleased !=0){
            mDragHelper.smoothSlideViewTo(mHeaderView, 0,0);
            invalidate();
            Log.d("DraggablePanel","Clicked top != 0");
        }else{
            Log.d("DraggablePanel","Clicked top == 0");
        }
        return true;
    }

    private boolean isViewHit(View view, int x, int y) {
        int[] viewLocation = new int[2];
        view.getLocationOnScreen(viewLocation);
        int[] parentLocation = new int[2];
        this.getLocationOnScreen(parentLocation);
        int screenX = parentLocation[0] + x;
        int screenY = parentLocation[1] + y;
        return screenX >= viewLocation[0] && screenX < viewLocation[0] + view.getWidth() &&
                screenY >= viewLocation[1] && screenY < viewLocation[1] + view.getHeight();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        measureChildren(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        int maxWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int maxHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

        setMeasuredDimension(resolveSizeAndState(maxWidth, widthMeasureSpec, 0),
                resolveSizeAndState(maxHeight, heightMeasureSpec, 0));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        Log.d(TAG,"onLayout Called");


            mDragRange = getHeight() - mHeaderView.getHeight();


        mHeaderView.layout(
                0,
                mTop,
                r,
                mTop + mHeaderView.getMeasuredHeight());

        mDescView.layout(
                0,
                mTop + mHeaderView.getMeasuredHeight(),
                r,
                mTop  + b);

    }



}
```

Here is the Layout where the above class has been used.

```
   <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewEvents"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <visio.com.eventpage.DraggablePanel
        android:id="@+id/draggablePanel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/viewHeader"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_event" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/viewDesc"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#FF00FF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:tag="desc"
            android:text="Loreum Loreum"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="35sp" />

    </visio.com.eventpage.DraggablePanel>


</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: still didn't work.

Comment: I had initialized it before in onFinishInflate method but it didn't work so I removed it. Then I tried settingOnClick listener in the MainActivity on the DraggablePanle still it didn't work.